# Does Python gRPC depend on libssl.so.1.1?

Tags: pip, conda, grpc

> **Does Python gRPC require libsso.so.1.1?**

I'm asking because I was able to install and import gRPC for Python in one environment using **pip**. However, after installing using **Conda** in another environment, I cannot import the module.

Looking further, I see that `site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.so` in the Conda install requires `libssl.so.1.1`, which is not the case for the pip-installed version.

**1. Installing using Conda (Cannot import due to missing libssl.so.1.1)**

```
>>> import grpc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "../miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found that `cygrpc.so` requires `libsso.so.1.1` by running the following. Meanwhile, running the same for `cygrpc.so` in the pip-installed version shows no such requirement.

```
readelf -d cygrpc.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x1b1f38 contains 35 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libssl.so.1.1]
 ...
```

**2. Installing using pip (successful)**

```
>>> import grpc
>>>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware that `grpcio` was available on Conda. Whoever was building and uploading those artifacts was unaffiliated with the gRPC team. As you can see, the last version they uploaded was in October (1.16.1), whereas PyPI is at 1.22. It also appears that whoever was uploading these was not paying attention to manylinux compliance. Whereas our artifacts on PyPI statically link in `libz`, `libcares`, `libcrypto`, and `libssl`, they appear to have been depending on the user to have those shared object libraries on their system.